# SFMC MobileConnect API flexibility

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sales-cloud, sms

Conceptually speaking, is the MobileConnect API flexible enough to build a component in Sales/Service Cloud to trigger an SMS in MobileConnect then provide a feedback loop or responses back into Sales/Service Cloud?

Basically, utilizing MobileConnect API in place of LiveMessage or a 3rd party like SMS Magic.

Comment: I would say most likely no it cannot. MobileConnect does not have the same flexibility (especially via API) that LiveMessage or SMS Magic does. For example, I do not believe via API there is any way to receive the recipients responses.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I could only find very minimal documentation for MC within API developer site.